# How can google captcha be validated on client side using ExtJs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, recaptcha

How can I validate google captcha on client side using ExtJS

```
 listeners: {
      'afterrender': function () {
           grecaptcha.render('reCaptcha', {
                'sitekey': '**key**',
                'callback' : 'correctCaptcha'
           });
      }
 }
```

I get the following error when I try to use call back function

> recaptcha__en.js:345 Uncaught TypeError: this.Mc.callback is not a
>   function

This is the console output I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Where and how you define `correctCaptcha` function?

Comment: I have added `correctCaptcha` within `listeners`

Comment: Its a scope issue than, I guess your callback function should be in the global scope.

Comment: @SergeyNovikov Is there any other way to do it on client side?

Comment: I think you can use `new Function()` and define it within your listener, read [this artice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

Comment: Don't really see how this is Ext related at all.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli, maybe your are right, but actually since ExtJS use closures everywhere and render DOM elements on demand using google recaptha can be realy tricky with this framework. Anyway there is a lot of other questions with "extjs" tag that actually is "general JS questions".

Comment: I agree with @Sergey, may be it is a general JS question but I am really facing the issues with the validation part of the captcha.

Answer (score 0):

Probably its a scope issue, make sure that your callback function `correctCaptcha` is in global (?) scope.

You can define your callback function within any nested function (your event listener for example) like this:

```
window.correctCaptcha = function() {}
```

Comment: can you give a small example for better understanding as I am still getting the same error

Comment: Updated my answer, I was wrong about `new Function()`.

Comment: sir the above solution didn't worked, getting the same error.

Comment: Ehm, can you try to open your UI, get this error and call `correctCaptcha()` from browser console? If error appears - your function somehow still not in the global scope and I dont know why...

Comment: You define `correctCaptcha` before `grecaptcha.render()` call?

Comment: yes, I have defined correctCaptcha before grecaptcha.render() call